# the use of the word "disposition"

Tags: vocabulary

> *Disposition*: a person's usual way of feeling or behaving; the tendency of a person to be happy, friendly, anxious, etc.

I just want to ask if  native speakers use this word in daily life? I want to use it, but I do not want to sound weird if it is not common to use.

Is it okay to say, "Depending on people's dispositions, they interpret the events different?" Or is there a sentence that makes more sense by using this word?

Comment: I apologize for the misguiding title. I was planning to post two words: one is junction and the other one is disposition. I've just recognized that I titled my post using the word "junction" instead of using the word "disposition". Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: I've corrected the title, Hizli Cublumbaga

Answer (score 4):

It's something of a learned word. I might use it that way in speech, but many people would not.

And I would say "they interpret the events differently"

Comment: Thanks so much for the explanation. Then, I will try to use "nature" or "character" instead of "disposition" so that I would not sound weird.

Comment: @HizliCublumbaga it all depends on the context - it might be more appropriate to say disposition in some situations (formal events). There's nothing really wrong with sounding intelligent! (although accidentally sounding pretentious is something to avoid)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is an everyday expression of a person who tries to speak English in an elegant and thoughtful way. It derives from the verb *dispose* - OED sense 6b of which means:

> 6b. To impart a physical tendency or inclination to; pa. pple.
>   inclined, liable: see disposed adj. 5. Also absol.

The noun ***disposition*** has a plethora of senses, but the important one here is sense 6:

> 6. Natural tendency or bent of the mind, esp. in relation to moral or social qualities; mental constitution or temperament; turn of mind.
>      Possibly of astrological origin: cf. the description of dispositions
>      as saturnine, jovial, martial, venereal, mercurial.
>
> ▸a1387   J. Trevisa tr. R. Higden Polychron. (St. John's Cambr.)
>   (1871) III. 113   Nouȝt by chaungynge of body, but by chaungynge of
>   disposicioun of wit and of semynge.
>
> 1393   J. Gower Confessio Amantis III. 19   After the disposition Of
>   glotony and dronkeship.
>
> 1475   Bk. Noblesse 51   If suche prophesies and influence of the
>   seide constellacions might be trew, yet..havyng a clene soule, may
>   turne the contrarie disposicion that jugement of constellacion or
>   prophesies signified.
>
> 1576   A. Fleming tr. Hippocrates in Panoplie Epist. 266   Men of
>   honeste and vertuous disposition.
>
> 1678   N. Wanley Wonders Little World v. ii. §81. 472/2   A man he was
>   of a fierce, bloody, and faithless disposition.
>
> 1779   J. Moore View Society & Manners France (1789) I. xvii. 128
>   Congenial with the phlegm and saturnine dispositions of the English.
>
> 1837   W. Whewell Hist. Inductive Sci. I. 136   The belief..that the
>   motions of the stars, and the dispositions and fortunes of men, may
>   come under some common conceptions and laws.
>
> 1841   G. P. R. James Brigand i   His disposition was naturally
>   cheerful and bright.
>
> > 

Comment: I'd add to these examples its use in pop lyrics, even by such elegant and thoughtful artists as The Rolling Stones: http://www.lyrics.com/lyrics/disposition

Comment: @GTonyJacobs Well I didn't go quite so far as Colin Fine, in describing it as "a learned word" - but I note he has been significantly up-voted!

Answer (score 0):

The context in which I most often see the word *disposition* used, even in fairly casual contexts, is when discussing children. For example, in

Advertisements:

> You can't predict the weather when you are out there hiking, but you can predict your **kid's disposition** if the weather gets bad. ([Advertising copy for a baby backpack rain cover](https://www.backcountry.com/deuter-kc-rain-cover))

Parenting advice:

> Those first signs of your new **baby's disposition** are usually right! It isn't just your imagination—she really does have preferences from the first moment. ([Holly Engel-Smothers & Susan M. Heim, *Boosting Your Baby's Brain Power*, 2008](https://books.google.com/books?id=8jw4Q6AHxzkC&lpg=PA87&ots=xCqj-zOwTO&dq=%22baby's%20disposition%22&pg=PA87#v=onepage&q=%22baby's%20disposition%22&f=false))

And conversation between parents:

> There are always lots of kiddos being carried or on the side crying, so it depends on your **DD's disposition**, the day itself, your willingness to deal with it or carry her, etc. ([Discussion board response to "Kids and Races: What Age?", Sept. 11, 2014](http://pandce.proboards.com/post/7351639/thread); "DD" usually stands for "dear daughter" in these discussions)

Perhaps not coincidentally, it also shows up in descriptions of pets. For example, from the [American Kennel Club](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.akc.org%2Fdog-breeds%2F&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS696US697&oq=site%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.akc.org%2Fdog-breeds%2F&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.6791j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#safe=active&q=site:http://www.akc.org/dog-breeds/%20disposition):

> The [Airedale](http://www.akc.org/dog-breeds/airedale-terrier/) has a **sweet disposition**, but when challenged, is not afraid to stand up for himself.

And from the UK's [Kennel Club](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.thekennelclub.org.uk%2F+disposition&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS696US697&oq=site%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.thekennelclub.org.uk%2F+disposition&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.11583j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8):

> [Siberian Husky Breed Standards](http://www.thekennelclub.org.uk/services/public/breed/standard.aspx?id=5141)
>   Characteristics: Medium size, moderate bone, well balanced proportions, ease and freedom of movement, and **good disposition**.

As a result of seeing it used this way so often it no longer feels particularly formal to me. However, I still might hesitate just a bit in using it to describe adult humans, for fear that I might bring to mind babies or dog breed descriptions. Of course, folks who don't often discuss or read about small children or dog breeds probably wouldn't have those associations.